# How to send JSON request using Jersey 2.x

Tags: java, json, jersey, reset

I am trying to send a rest request using Jersey 2.x. All the samples I can find use Jersey 1.x.

This is how it is done in Jersey 1.X

```
String jsonPayload = "{\"name\":\"" + folderName + "\",\"description\":\"" + folderDescription + "\"}";
WebResource webResource = client.resource(restRequestUrl);
ClientResponse response =
    webResource.header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthString)
    header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    post(ClientResponse.class, jsonPayload);
```

How do I do the equivalent in Jersey 2.x?

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
WebTarget target = client.target(m_docs_base_url + "/users/items");
String jsonPayload = "{\"info\":\"" + "smith" + "\"}";
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.request("text/plain");
Response response = invocationBuilder.get(jsonPayload);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question but for the benefit of others looking for similar things.
Your Jersey 1.x example is a POST request. So you only need to make changes in

```
Response response = invocationBuilder.get(jsonPayload);
```

to the JAX-RS 2.0 way

```
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =
    target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("Content-Type", "application/json");

JSONObject jsonObject  = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("info", "smith");
Entity<?> entity = Entity.entity(jsonObject.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

Response response = invocationBuilder.post(entity, Response.class);
```

See examples using Using JAX-RS Client API
https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html

Jersey 1.x to Jersey 2.x migration guide
https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/migration.html

Answer (score -3):

Did you look at the Jersey client documentation?

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4692

Remember to use post() method with your JSON payload and not get() method as in that example.